# Dynamic templates in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: java, scala, dynamic, playframework-2.0

There is `TemplateLoader` in `Play 1.0` for generating templates in runtime.

Is there any solution to dynamically load template in `Play 2.0`? Or can I somehow convert it to scala code for using `Eval`?

For example: I want to store some templates in the database, so that certain users could edit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the relevant code is in `framework/src/play/src/main/scala/system/ApplicationProvider.scala` in the Play-2.0 directory, particularly the `ReloadableApplication` class. I'm unsure how this compiling on the fly would suit you, since you don't want to do it when the template is requested (it is slow). Which means that storing in a database doesn't quite make sense: you don't want to store the template source code, but rather the compiled template object.

For arguments sake, if you just wrote the templates to the `app/views` directory, you could leave Play to compile them at its leisure. But then, beware, because they probably won't compile on a production system.

Answer (score 3):

Play 2.0 already compiles your templates to object methods, so you don't have to 'dynamically load' them!

Consider this simple template called `app/views/test.scala.html`.

```
@(num:Long) 
Your number is @num
```

It becomes a Scala method of `views.html` called `test`. Evaluate it with this code:

```
val msg : String = views.html.test(23).toString()
```

You don't have to use html views only. To use templates with strings, use the [`play.api.templates.Txt`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.templates.Txt) derived classes. This is a template called `app/views/quick.scala.txt`:

```
@(id:Long)Your id is @id
```

It becomes a method `views.txt.quick` and is used:

```
val msg2 : String = views.txt.quick(32).body
```

You can find out more in [the documentation for the the play.api.templates](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.templates.package) package.

Comment: Thank you, but the question is about how to generate new template in runtime. For example, I want to store some templates in the database, so that certain users could edit them.

Comment: Ah, a more complicated proposition. It seems the relevant code is in `framework/src/play/src/main/scala/system/ApplicationProvider.scala` in the Play-2.0 directory, and I would look at the `ReloadableApplication` class. But this seems to pass the task to sbt in the background. Of course, you should consider whether you _want_ your users to be able to write templates. Given that they have full programming power at their command, aren't you opening yourself to a massive hack? All the best

Comment: Thank you! I think it's what I'm looking for. And thanks again for caution, but of course this functions will be available only on development server for users that already have opportunity to destroy it. Please update your answer so I can accept it.